# Symfony2 and filter, right strategy

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony, filter

I'm asking what is the best strategy for filtering with Symfony2.

I want to filter a table of entities (hotels). This filter should allow me to :

- choose hotels with or whitout email, with or without web site etc.
- choose hotels based on state and/or city (relation OneToMany)
- choose what information I want to display on the table with checkboxs (for example display "email adress" on the hotel table, but do not display "tel" or "web site").

First I think to build the filter form on the HotelController. When the filter is submitted, I had a FlashBag for every $_POST sended, redirect to the same page, and if there are FlashBag I send cookies to the $reponse. Then I display the table filtered with data who are on the cookie.

But I dont't really like this, cause I had a very big indexAction() on the HotelController, and I think it'as not really clean to change $_POST to FlasBag to Cookie, is it ? I do this redirection, cause by refreshing the page, data are not posted again.

I'm also asking a question, to prevent a too big IndexAction() method, **can I put some code to another method**, for exemple a method PostToFlashBag() and another FlashBagToCookie(), **or every method on a Controller has to end with the word "Action" and must be accessible with the router** ?

Then, I think to another thing : had an entity "Filter", with every row I need. For exemple "WithEmail", "DisplayTel" etc.. Then I can build a FilterType easily, and update the Filter entitie, to redirect to the same page (again, to prevent reposting data if the user refreshes the page). Finally, I can display the table with the object Filter, with a method on the HotelRepository.

That seems great, but I'm a little worry because the filter entity will only have one entry, and I have to find the Filter(1). **Due to MVC, is it correct to have a model with only one entry** ?

**What strategy would you choose (maybe another one) ?** I'm interesting to learn good practice with MVC and Symfony2 devloppemnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a dedicated model class - let's call it `Filter` - that will receive the values input by the user, is definitely the way to go.

More over, use the Symfony2 form on this input, so you can have validation, and be sure that the `withEmail`is trully a boolean, etc. From you `Filter`, build you SQL/Doctrine query and return what your controller have to return, be it a view, or raw datas.

You can have **any method you want in a controller**. After all, controllers in Symfony2 are plain old PHP objects. They only have to implement `ContainerAwareInterface`. Usually they inherits `Controller`, but this inheritance only brings some proxy methods, like `getDoctrine` or `render`.

The only convention is that methods which are used as route must end with `Action`